# Android's Google map usage Limits

Tags: android, google-maps, unity-game-engine

Is Android's Google map limited in usage like GoogleMaps API?

I'm asking because I have to decide which service to use for geolocalization in a Unity3D game:

My main choices are so far:

- Host my own OpenStreetMap cluster (and pay for hosting, I see some technical problems: server configuration is not so easy even following their walkthrough, and I think unless I have a lot of users this may not be the cheapest solution)
- Use GoogleMaps API (and pay 0.5$ for each 1000 maps view, after 25.000 daily)
- Use Android's Google maps (I have to develop that natively in a Fragment, and maybe do I have to pay something for it?)

I cannot find exact pricing for Android native maps, is that the same as GoogleMaps? If so then why I'm not asked for a API token?

Comment: Check this link. When you select the app type, you get to see the plans. https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Comment: So if the app is free on the play store, I get free static maps with unlimited usage? What if there are In-App purchases?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Google maps are free for android.

Comment: So no need to use API key/ pay anything as long as I use the native Java Map (Like MapFragment). ? I would like an answer that document that (maybe linking documentation or claims by google developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the table shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details), the **Standard license** provides an *Unlimited free usage* for ([see note](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#sup_1))

> Includes paid apps through an online store and internal Android apps as allowed by the Standard Plan Terms of Service.

Also, on the [same page](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/), you can use **Standard license** (free) plan for:

- Free: For free and publicly available apps/websites, use the Standard Plan
- Paid: For Android/iOS, you may charge a fee via the Play or App stores for your app and use the Standard Plan
- Invite only: Android apps built for private use may use the Standard Plan

So, if your Android application is free and publicly available, or paid via Play Store or built for private use, you can use the **Standard Plan** (free).